# Не могу запустить webdriver в Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium

При попытке запустить webdriver, выдает ошибку File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 50, in **init**
    self.NATIVE_EVENTS_ALLOWED and self.profile.native_events_enabled)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'native_events_enabled'

Сделал так

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

но при запуске прога просто висит. Жесткий загружается на полную и ничего не происходит. Geckodriver лежит в папке home. Подскажите как исправить? На винде прекрасно работает просто driver = webdriver.Firefox(), на линуксе не могу запустить.

Comment: `типа str object has no attribute native чего-то там` `Подскажите как исправить?` у вас ошибка где-то, вы ее постарайтесь не повторять :) Когда жалуйтесь на ошибку в коде, приводите ее полностью, а то телепаты в отпуске :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте явно указать путь к драйверу

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/geckodriver', firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: не работает, также висит и всё, ничего не происходит